# How to configure karma so typescript source files would be debuggable

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, webpack, karma-runner

I've downloaded a seed project [Angular2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/tree/material2) and got it up and running without an issue. One inconvenience that I have with it is debugging source files under unit tests. All `*.spec.ts` files are loaded into browser and debugable so `map` files are generated for them at least. When I step into a source file under test I get something like this:

[image: Source file in browser]

karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js');

config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    exclude: [ ],
    files: [ { pattern: './config/spec-bundle.js', watched: false } ],
    preprocessors: { './config/spec-bundle.js': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'] },
    webpack: testWebpackConfig,
    coverageReporter: {
      dir : 'coverage/',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type: 'json' },
        { type: 'html' }
      ]
    },
webpackServer: { noInfo: true },
reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage' ],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: [
  'Chrome'
],
singleRun: false
});
};
```

webpack.test.js:

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
        root: helpers.root('src'),
    },
    module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: [helpers.root('node_modules')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [
            helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs'),
            helpers.root('node_modules/@angular2-material'),
            helpers.root('node_modules/@angular')
      ]}
   ],
loaders: [
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
    query: {
      compilerOptions: {
          removeComments: true
      }
    },
    exclude: [/\.e2e\.ts$/]
  },
  { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader', exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')] },
  { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'], exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')] },
  { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader', exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')] }
],
postLoaders: [
{
    test: /\.(js|ts)$/, loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
    include: helpers.root('src'),
    exclude: [
      /\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$/,
      /node_modules/
    ]
  }
]
},
plugins: [
new DefinePlugin({
  'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV),
  'HMR': false,
  'process.env': {
    'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV),
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV),
    'HMR': false,
  }
}),
],
tslint: {
    emitErrors: false,
    failOnHint: false,
    resourcePath: 'src'
  },
node: {
    global: 'window',
    process: false,
    crypto: 'empty',
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
}
};
```

spec-bundle.js:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');
require('ts-helpers');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('rxjs/Rx');
var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');
testing.setBaseTestProviders(
  browser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
  browser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
);
var testContext = require.context('../src', true, /\.spec\.ts/);
function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}
var modules = requireAll(testContext);
```

This configuration is as in starter package with minor if any modifications. Could you tell me how to modify this configuration so the `.ts` source files would be debugable with coverage statistics.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my project (which isn't the Angular2 Webpack Starter, but I believe has the same cause.)

WebPack, by default, doesn't pass source maps up to Karma unless the file extension is `.js` (or `.jsx` if you're using React). In a setup like this one, Karma+WebPack just transpiles the `.ts` files (or `.tsx`) straight from TypeScript to JavaScript and serves them under the same file name.

I found a solution that worked for me [on the GitHub Issues page for `karma-webpack`](https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack/issues/109#issuecomment-224961264). The trick is to inject `webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin` with a widened file filter into the webpack config. For you, that should look something like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
// in your config.set:
plugins: [
  // existing plugins go here
  new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    filename: null, // if no value is provided the sourcemap is inlined
    test: /\.(ts|js)($|\?)/i // process .js and .ts files only
  })
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll accept it when I get a minute to verify it.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I also added `devtool: false` and `mode: 'development'` for webpack 4

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment out **Istanbul loader** inside your webpack.test.config.js, like this

```
    // {
    //   enforce: 'post',
    //   test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
    //   loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
    //   include: helpers.root('src'),
    //   exclude: [
    //     /\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$/,
    //     /node_modules/
    //   ]
    // }
```

then simply run:

```
 npm run watch:test
```